# How to Play Video from URL in Android?

Tags: android

I wrote code for play video from URL. But I am getting `UNABLE TO PLAY VIDEO` message.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvtCk1wZ7LM&feature=player_detailpage");
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();

}
```

```
<VideoView
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:id="@+id/video"></VideoView>
```

Comment: Hi i get the code, its very simple

Comment: Just write socket programm with WIFI printer IP

Comment: can you put the LogCat trace so we can take alook a it

Answer (score 0):

You could simple fire an Intent to play the video by another app.
Here, Youtube app will detect a Youtube Video, and will prompt the dialog to play the video on your behalf.

```
    String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvtCk1wZ7LM";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
```

But if you really want to integrate a video player inside your app, I strongly recommand you to take a look at the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just create video view then add a new media controller to it, set the video URL in the video view and start the video it will work.

Add the below Code into your **MainActivity.java** file.

```
    @Override

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         try {
         setContentView(R.layout.videodisplay);
         String link="http://s1133.photobucket.com/albums/m590/Anniebabycupcakez/?action=view&amp; current=1376992942447_242.mp4";
         VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
         MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
         mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
         Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
         videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
         videoView.setVideoURI(video);
         videoView.start();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
         Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }
```

You better try it on offline file to make sure that the video viewer is working fine (the video is compatible with the device) then play it from YouTube online.

Comment: Please, don't just post code. A little bit of explanation will help others understand

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple and easy way to play the video.

xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingLeft="2px" android:paddingRight="2px"
android:paddingTop="2px" android:paddingBottom="2px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <VideoView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/VideoView"></VideoView>

</LinearLayout>
```

java file.....

```
public class VideoPlayerController extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.video);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        // Set video link (mp4 format )
        Uri video = Uri.parse("mp4 video link");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: i also try same code for mp4 video format but i didnt get any result

Answer (score -1):

some file format like youtube video file format cant open in video view.
videoview only support system file format can  opend it like mp4 . 3gp . other...
for open fly video format you must use **surfeview** and create class that can handl this video type
and for get video from link use **inputstream** (dont use string)
other easy way to show youtube video is just use Intent.View,url(your video uri)
https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: This is very hard to understand. Please edit to clarify what you mean, especially about what formats are supported in particular.

Answer (score -1):

Use Exo-Player , it is better choice to play videos and having lot of functionallity --Follow [Exo Player Docs](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: OP has provided (apparently non-functioning) code for how to play a video from a URL in Android. If doing so with Exo Player is easier, a code snippet showing how to use Exo Player to do what OP is trying to do would be a useful answer.